# Google Dart Remove DropDown Duplicates

Tags: json, drop-down-menu, dictionary, hashmap, dart

I'm attempting to remove duplicates from a Map to populate a dropdown list.  However, I haven't been able to successfully remove them.  The dropdown fills with double the amount of data (JSON) than what actually exists.  If there is a simple way to do this, please let me know.  Also, please let me know if you need more information.

Dart code:

```
var jsonString = response;
   //var dropDownValue = shroot.querySelector("#asset");
   SelectElement dropDown = shroot.querySelector("#asset");

   Map jsonObject = JSON.decode(jsonString) as Map;
       dropDownList = jsonObject["eee"] as List<Map>;

   LinkedHashMap<String, Map> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map>();

   for(Map d in dropDownList)
    {
      dropDown.children.add(new OptionElement(data: d['displayName'], value: d['displayName']));

      print(d);
      print(d["id"]);
      print(d["displayName"]);
    }
```

Dart Attempt 2:

```
var ddValues = dropDownList
     // extract the 'displayValue'
     .map((e) => e['displayName'])
     // create a set to eliminate duplicates
     .toSet().toList()
     // sort the result 
     // sort changes the list it is called - it doesn't return a new list
     // therefore we have to chain it using `..` instead of `.`
     ..sort();

     ddValues.forEach((e) {
       print(e);
      dropDown.children.add(new OptionElement(data: e, value: e));
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how your data looks like but I guess you want something like

```dart
void main() {

  // to make the code here shorter I remove the elements from JSON that don't have any effect on the processing. This code should work the same with the full JSON posted in your question.
  var values =  {
                 "serviceResponseValue":[
                    {"displayName":"name"},
                    {"displayName":"name"},
                    {"displayName":"name1"},
                    {"displayName":"Processes"}
                 ],
                 "messages":{"messages":[]}
              };


  var ddValues = values['serviceResponseValue']
  // extract the 'displayValue'
  .map((e) => e['displayName'])
  // create a set to eliminate duplicates
  .toSet().toList()
  // sort the result 
  // sort changes the list it is called - it doesn't return a new list
  // therefore we have to chain it using `..` instead of `.`
  ..sort();

  ddValues.forEach((e) {
    print(e);
    //dropDown.children.add(new OptionElement(data: e, value: e));
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes works fine here. I took your code and your JSON and run it. Output is `Processes
name
name1`